# prevent overflow of absolutely positioned dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get the height and width of a dynamically generated div inside a loop.

### Details

I'm dynamically setting the left and top values of a positioned absolute div.  This div is in a loop, thus its width, height and position change at an interval n. 
(It's basically a div that appears at random places on a page every n seconds.)

The challenge I'm facing is that this div needs to be inside the parent at all times, `<body>` tag in this case. I have it set to `position:relative` and even `overflow:hidden` though it won't help.

Here's a fiddle to make things easier. 
[Fiddle 1 outside the loop](http://jsfiddle.net/yMT56/1/) , [Fiddle 0 insdie the loop](http://jsfiddle.net/yMT56/)

You will see that because the x and y values are randomly generated the div overflows.

I have found that in order to keep the div in the body it's height and width must be retrieved and calculated with the parent to get the difference in size.
[image]
So I can use it the css like

`var heightdiff = parentHeight - divHeight;`

`var widthdiff = parentWidth - divWidth;`

in the css via jQuery

`top: Math.floor((Math.random()*heightdiff)+0;`

`left: Math.floor((Math.random()*widthdiff)+0;`

Perhaps I'm making a simple mistake but I've tried everything I can think of. To recap all I need to do is to get the height and width of div.

Comment: To be more clear about what your asking, you need to get the Height/Width of a div element you create in JS before adding it to the DOM. The loop has little to do with it.

Comment: You're right. But the depth of the content that goes inside the div can affect its size if I were to put different length of stuff on each loop.

Comment: Doesn't matter, until the content is added to the DOM the jQuery `.height()` and `.width()` methods would return 0. That is shown in both of your Fiddles. Another option you might have is to estimate the size based on the HTML content (i.e. number of text characters)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will experiment a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your script :

http://jsfiddle.net/yMT56/1/

Why using document as base ?

```
var docw = $(document).width();
var doch = $(document).height();
```

Use body

```
var docw = $('body').width();
var doch = $('body').height();
```

Or better, div's parent (requires you to append your div to a container before) :

```
var docw = $newdiv.parent().width();
var doch = $newdiv.parent().height();
```

The problem here is that the div has no content and so on no width and height at the moment you calculate it. So I created it at the beginning (notice i added `<body>` tag in the html part : i don't know how fiddlejs handles this case) :

```
$newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'display':'block'
    }).html("Hi there, this should appear with in the body.<br/> Just wait it will overflow").appendTo( 'body' );
    //parent size, in this case body
    var docw = $('body').width();
    var doch = $('body').height();
     //calculating div size, before it's set, wrong!!
    var divh = $newdiv.height();
    var divw = $newdiv.width();
```

I also added a Math.max control to be sure results won't be negatives, especially in case div is larger than his parent.

```
//positions for x and y
var posx = Math.max((Math.random() * (wdiff) +1).toFixed(), 0);
var posy = Math.max((Math.random() * (hdiff) +1).toFixed(), 0);
```

And, at the end, only put position for the div :

```
$newdiv.css({
    'left':posx+'px',
    'top':posy+'px'
}).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000, function(){
```

Maybe with that solution, a first div will be displayed before loop starts. A solution would be to use `visibility:hidden` property, to hide div but always be able to got his width and height.

Comment: Using `display=none` appears to work for this solution, and the element will not be displayed before being faded in. [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/u3w9N/2/)

Comment: @OliverH great suggestions. I'm testing them.

Comment: @Nunners there still seems to be overflowing in your link.